# OnCollisionEnter not working Unity3d 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

My goal is to change object color when it collides with something.
The object itself is a capsuleCollider with some particle effects.
The `CapsuleCollider` is tracking where player watches.

```
telePoint.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(new Vector3(tempHit.point.x, player.transform.position.y, tempHit.point.z));
```

I tried using this script connected to the collider i position where a player is watching :

```
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {

    Debug.LogError("COLLISION ??" + col.gameObject.name);
    if (!col.gameObject.name.Contains("floor")) {

        player.GetComponent<telePortationScript>().teleEnabled = false;
    }
    else {
        Debug.LogError("Collision with -> " + col.gameObject.name);
        player.GetComponent<telePortationScript>().teleEnabled = true;
    }

}
```

The `CapsuleCollider` that I am moving has also a `RigidBody` component and is Kinetic is enabled. Other objects have only colliders and no rigid bodies.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Both objects have a collider and the moving one has a rigidbody (non-kinetic)? Here is some example how the code could look like http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on your code more?

Comment: What is currently happening? Do the debug statements fire at all or are they not showing up either?

Comment: The debug statment does not fire..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marked my Capsule Collider as Trigger and added a function

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
```

And it worked !